# How to create static views in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, view, hive, bigdata, hiveql

How to create a static view in Hive? Like I am creating below view,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TMP AS 
SELECT 1 AS LEVEL_ID,'URBAN' AS ITEM_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS LEVEL_ID,'RURAL' AS ITEM_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 9999 AS LEVEL_ID,'ALL' AS ITEM_CODE;
```

it is throwing below error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException No valid
>   privileges Required privilege( Table) not available in input
>   privileges The required privileges:

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Given query won't work as it is not fetching data from any table. In hive, while creating a static view, you still need to fetch data from a table. If it would have been oracle, you could have fetch from dummy table directly.

So there are 2 approaches that you can do to create a static view.

1. Point it to any existing table and use where 1=1 condition.
2. Create a dummy table and select it using from dummy table like below.

   create table dummy (id int)

   insert into dummy(1)

   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TMP1 (LEVEL_ID , ITEM_CODE  ) AS 
   SELECT 1 AS LEVEL_ID,'URBAN' AS ITEM_CODE from dummy
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 AS LEVEL_ID,'RURAL' AS ITEM_CODE from dummy
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 9999 AS LEVEL_ID,'ALL' AS ITEM_CODE from dummy;

Answer (score 0):

Do check if you have the necessary permissions in the hive warehouse and try to use any other database to create your view.

Sometimes, the default database is not given permission for all the users.

If you are using Kerberos cluster, you need to check whether the Hive user has the necessary sentry roles or not.

Or else :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TMP1 (LEVEL_ID , ITEM_CODE  ) AS 
SELECT 1 AS LEVEL_ID,'URBAN' AS ITEM_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS LEVEL_ID,'RURAL' AS ITEM_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 9999 AS LEVEL_ID,'ALL' AS ITEM_CODE;
```

Comment: I am able to create other view like CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TMP AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1;  but unable to create static views.

Comment: Looks bit strange, I executed your query in my vm and it ran without any issue.

Comment: I have edited my answer, check it whether it works or not.

Comment: No luck, your query also didn't execute !